# 'interface' declarations can only be used in TypeScript files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I made a little web site and I have some errors in it. My file is tsx but still gives this errors 'interface' declarations can only be used in TypeScript files.

[image]

But I use interface in other file but there is not such error

[image]

I don't know  what to do. https://github.com/g1org11/redeplorers

src>components>destinationComponets>Destination.tsx.

I try to fix this error with ChatGPT/search in Google but unfortunately I don't find any solution.

Comment: Please [do not post a link to a painting of the code or error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)! You can [edit] your question to include the code as [formatted text](/help/formatting).

Comment: [This](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40283) suggest either renaming the files twice by changing it's extension (tsx > ts > tsx) or restarting ts-server.

Comment: restart LSP typescript

Comment: dont work  restart